# Google OAuth 2.0 and Java. Is it safe to locally store access tokens?

Tags: java, access-control, oauth, google

I Installed this Java app:

https://github.com/andresoviedo/google-drive-ftp-adapter

The program asks permission to see my Google-Drive files and then stores an
access-token on my local harddisk. Filename: 'StoredCredential'.
The next time the app needs to access the files it uses the token to authenticate.
What are the risks of this method and are there ways to make it more safe?

Thanx for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the specific source code piece([GoogleDrive.java](https://github.com/andresoviedo/google-drive-ftp-adapter/blob/master/src/main/java/org/andresoviedo/apps/gdrive_ftp_adapter/model/GoogleDrive.java)) that handles credential file creation/initialization, I found this:

***Line 449:***

```
/** Directory to store user credentials. */
private final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR;
```

***Line 473:***

```
public GoogleDrive(Properties configuration) {
    DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File("data/google/" + configuration.getProperty("account", "default"));

    try {
        // initialize the data store factory
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        // initialize the transport
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se pudo inicializar la API de Google");
    }
    init();
}
```

Can you see the that the credential file is stored at `"data/google"` using a [relative path](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/relative-pathname/) on Unix-like? This means that you will not want to run this software on your `/tmp` directory, since the credentials could be accessible by more people that you want. If the parameter set is `account=default` the path shall be `$CURRENT_DIR/data/google/default`. This is the default behavior of `java.io.File` and a longer answer is found at stackexchange:

- [Java file path in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627951/java-file-path-in-linux)

**Tips to make this thing a little safer**(on the StoredCredential perspective):

- Don't run java as root/admin. NEVER! There is no need for if from filesystem to network. FTP binds on a port that is higher than `1024` so, there is no need to run as root
- Keep `data/` under strict directory permission, like `rwx` only to you, the owner.

There are other security measures that you could take related to local port bind and local user that could access it(iptables), but it will get out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Can a token like this be used on other machines?

Comment: I don't know. I need to know what kind of information is stored on this token. It could become invalid if some host-specific information is stored on the file. But, if these security measures are not taken, this token could lead to full acces on the app that was authorized(google drive on this case).

Answer (score 1):

Giving an app your OAuth token is kind of like giving them a limited-use password. In this case it's a password they they can use to get into your Google Drive, but they can't use it to get into your Gmail. If you're not comfortable with the app saving that key to storage, then don't use that app.

Also, you can review which OAuth tokens you've granted and revoke the ones you no longer want to have active. Click your picture in the top-right corner of a Google page and then select "My Account" and click "Connected Apps and Sites" under "security".

Direct link: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions